# Base a logic on another observation's value

Tags: stata

I've got a dataset where unfortunately the dataset is split in two.

We've got patient characteristics and treatment information.

Luckily, they are coined by a patient identifier.

In this example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str32 record_id str16 redcap_event_name byte gender
"007128de18ce5cb1635b8f27c5435ff3" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"007128de18ce5cb1635b8f27c5435ff3" "treatments_arm_1" .
"00abd7bdb6283dd0ac6b97271608a122" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"00abd7bdb6283dd0ac6b97271608a122" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0142103f84693c6eda416dfc55f65de1" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0142103f84693c6eda416dfc55f65de1" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"0153826d93a58d7e1837bb98a3c21ba8" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0153826d93a58d7e1837bb98a3c21ba8" "treatments_arm_1" .
"01c729ac4601e36f245fd817d8977917" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"01c729ac4601e36f245fd817d8977917" "treatments_arm_1" .
"01dd90093fbf201a1f357e22eaff6b6a" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"01dd90093fbf201a1f357e22eaff6b6a" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0208e14dcabc43dd2b57e2e8b117de4d" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0208e14dcabc43dd2b57e2e8b117de4d" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"0210f575075e5def7ffa77530ce17ef0" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0210f575075e5def7ffa77530ce17ef0" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"022cc7a9397e81cf58cd9111f9d1db0d" "treatments_arm_1" .
"022cc7a9397e81cf58cd9111f9d1db0d" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"02afd543116a22fc7430620727b20bb5" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"02afd543116a22fc7430620727b20bb5" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0303ef0bd5d256cca1c836e2b70415ac" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0303ef0bd5d256cca1c836e2b70415ac" "treatments_arm_1" .
"041b2b0cac589d6e3b65bb924803cf1a" "treatments_arm_1" .
"041b2b0cac589d6e3b65bb924803cf1a" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0536317a2bbb936e85c3eb8294b076da" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0536317a2bbb936e85c3eb8294b076da" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"06161d4668f217937cac0ac033d8d199" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"06161d4668f217937cac0ac033d8d199" "treatments_arm_1" .
"065e151f8bcebb27fabf8b052fd70566" "treatments_arm_1" .
"065e151f8bcebb27fabf8b052fd70566" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"07196414cd6bf89d94a33e149983d102" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"07196414cd6bf89d94a33e149983d102" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0721c38f8275dab504fc53aebcc005ce" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0721c38f8275dab504fc53aebcc005ce" "treatments_arm_1" .
"07bef516d53279a3f5e477d56d552a2b" "treatments_arm_1" .
"07bef516d53279a3f5e477d56d552a2b" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"08678829b7e0ee6a01b17974b4d19cfa" "treatments_arm_1" .
"08678829b7e0ee6a01b17974b4d19cfa" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"08bb6c65e63c499ea19ac24d5113dd94" "treatments_arm_1" .
"08bb6c65e63c499ea19ac24d5113dd94" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"08f036417500c332efd555c76c4654a0" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"08f036417500c332efd555c76c4654a0" "treatments_arm_1" .
"090c54d021b4b21c7243cec01efbeb91" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"090c54d021b4b21c7243cec01efbeb91" "treatments_arm_1" .
"09166bb44e4c5cdb8f40d402f706816e" "treatments_arm_1" .
"09166bb44e4c5cdb8f40d402f706816e" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0930159addcdc35e7dc18812522d4377" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0930159addcdc35e7dc18812522d4377" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"096844af91d2e266767775b0bee9105e" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"096844af91d2e266767775b0bee9105e" "treatments_arm_1" .
"09884af1bb9d59803de0c74d6df57c23" "treatments_arm_1" .
"09884af1bb9d59803de0c74d6df57c23" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"09e03748da35e9d799dc5d8ddf1909b5" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"09e03748da35e9d799dc5d8ddf1909b5" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0a4ce4a7941ff6d1f5c217bf5a9a3bf9" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0a4ce4a7941ff6d1f5c217bf5a9a3bf9" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0a5db40dc58e97927b407c9210aab7ba" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0a5db40dc58e97927b407c9210aab7ba" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"0a73c992955231650965ed87e3bd52f6" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0a73c992955231650965ed87e3bd52f6" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"0a84ab77fff74c247a525dfde8ce988c" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0a84ab77fff74c247a525dfde8ce988c" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"0af333ae400f75930125bb0585f0dcf5" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0af333ae400f75930125bb0585f0dcf5" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0af73334d9d2166191f3385de48f15d2" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0af73334d9d2166191f3385de48f15d2" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"0b341ac8f396a8cdb88b7c658f66f653" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0b341ac8f396a8cdb88b7c658f66f653" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0b35cf4beb830b361d7c164371f25149" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0b35cf4beb830b361d7c164371f25149" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0b3e110c9765e14a5c41fadcc3cfc300" "oprettelse_arm_1" .
"0b6681f0f441e69c26106ab344ac0733" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0b6681f0f441e69c26106ab344ac0733" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0b8d8253a8415275dbc2619e039985bb" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0b8d8253a8415275dbc2619e039985bb" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0b92c26375117bf42945c04d8d6573d4" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0b92c26375117bf42945c04d8d6573d4" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0ba961f437f43105c357403c920bdef1" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"0ba961f437f43105c357403c920bdef1" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0bb601fabe1fdfa794a5272408997a2f" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"0bb601fabe1fdfa794a5272408997a2f" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0c75b36e91363d596dc46bd563c3f5ef" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0c75b36e91363d596dc46bd563c3f5ef" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0d461328a3bae7164ce7d3a10f366812" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0d461328a3bae7164ce7d3a10f366812" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0d4cc4eb459301a804cbef22914f44a3" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0d4cc4eb459301a804cbef22914f44a3" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0d4e29e11bb94e922112089f3fec61ef" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0d4e29e11bb94e922112089f3fec61ef" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0d513c74d667f55c8f4a9836c304149c" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"0d513c74d667f55c8f4a9836c304149c" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0da25de126bb3b3ee565eff8888004c2" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0da25de126bb3b3ee565eff8888004c2" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0db9ae1f2201577f431b7603d0819fa6" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0db9ae1f2201577f431b7603d0819fa6" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"0dd8a681f6a5d4c888831a591e57a747" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0dd8a681f6a5d4c888831a591e57a747" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0e05d6958d878368b5fb831211fad6a1" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"0e05d6958d878368b5fb831211fad6a1" "treatments_arm_1" .
"0e3ff41e0e2b2cb5ec336fd0b04e5d44" "treatments_arm_1" .
end
label values gender gender_
label def gender_ 1 "Kvinde", modify
label def gender_ 2 "Mand", modify
```

Notice that gender is missing for all of `event name` "treatments_arm_1". However, in reality they have the gender of the same `record_id` but with `event_name` "oprettelse_arm_1".

I would like to say: "For each `record_id`, replace `gender` of `treatments_arm_1` for the `gender` in `oprettelse_arm_1`. But I'm not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't touch on the possibility of a change in reported gender. But this should get you most if not all of the way:

```
clear
input str32 record_id str16 redcap_event_name byte gender
"007128de18ce5cb1635b8f27c5435ff3" "oprettelse_arm_1" 1
"007128de18ce5cb1635b8f27c5435ff3" "treatments_arm_1" .
"00abd7bdb6283dd0ac6b97271608a122" "oprettelse_arm_1" 2
"00abd7bdb6283dd0ac6b97271608a122" "treatments_arm_1" .
end 

bysort record_id (gender) : gen OK = gender == gender[1] | missing(gender)

by record_id : replace gender = gender[1] if OK 

list, sepby(record_id)

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                        record_id   redcap_event_n~e   gender   OK |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 007128de18ce5cb1635b8f27c5435ff3   oprettelse_arm_1        1    1 |
  2. | 007128de18ce5cb1635b8f27c5435ff3   treatments_arm_1        1    1 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
  3. | 00abd7bdb6283dd0ac6b97271608a122   oprettelse_arm_1        2    1 |
  4. | 00abd7bdb6283dd0ac6b97271608a122   treatments_arm_1        2    1 |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is a standard application of `by:` on which see e.g. [this tutorial](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004). If we sort on `gender` within each identifier, any missing values will be sorted to the end of each block of observations. Then we check that either `gender` is equal to the first value in each block, or else missing. If all values are missing, then missings are replaced by missings, with no harm done. If different non-missing values are recorded for each identifier, no changes are made. Otherwise the single non-missing value is copied uniformly across the block.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I understand some basic applications of by: however I'm unsure how exactly this is working. I think "replace gender = gender[1]" is the part I'm confused. What is the [1] doing?

Comment: It refers to the first observation in each group. This is explained in the linked paper and at [U] 13.7.2 in the User's Manual.